# jQuery fields with default text before focus of text area

Tags: jquery, html

How do I get the jquery to have a 'textarea' include default message like an 'input' box. I am very new to jQuery and cannot seem to figure this out. I do apologize for the need to ask this.

I have done a lot of research looking to incorporate very simple jQuery functionality into a site. I am really attempting to limit the extra js footprint to minimal scripts. Not large plugin scripts. In my research I have found a lot of help in doing so.

I have a couple of custom search queries which I have working as close to intended as I am able to make them. With those little search boxes I use a small script for replacing the content of the 'input' to a custom message like a "search for..." until someone (focuses) types in the box. This little script works beautifully. But I also would like the same script to do the same in the comment area.

```
$('#outputList, #outputList2').removeClass('no-display');
$(document).on("blur", "#inputBox, #inputBox2, #commentArea", function(){
    var default_value = $(this).attr("rel");
    if ($(this).val() === ""){
        $(this).val(default_value);
    }
}).on("focus", "#inputBox, #inputBox2, #commentArea", function(){
    var default_value = $(this).attr("rel");
    if ($(this).val() === default_value){
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

The basic html is as follows. For the comment box...

```
<textarea name="comment" id="commentArea" class="input-block-level" rows="6" rel="Leave a Comment…"></textarea><!--text between the text areas tags does not get removed -->
```

For the search boxes...

```
<input type="text" id="inputBox" value="Search for..." rel="Search for..." />
<ul id="outputList" class="align-left no-display">
    <!-- list to be filtered -->
</ul>

<input type="text" id="inputBox2" value="Search for..." rel="Search for..." />
<ul id="outputList2" class="align-left no-display">
   <!-- list to be filtered -->
</ul>
```

As can bee seen here on my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pelligea/ehwRU/). Instantly on load the Search Boxes have the value field as default. And on losing focus goes to the rel field.

The textarea aquires the rel field on losing focus but does not work with a value field to start.

I am aware of a placeholder through HTML but I would like to have it the same format as the search boxes and act in the same manner. Is this possible?

I have searched and found a lot of answers but none seem to get the comment box to have the deafult field working on load. Thank you all in advance for your help and time.

I am running on the following if it helps. Wordpress 3.5.1, jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery UI 1.9, php 5.4, and MySql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30.

Comment: There's nothing that puts the initial textarea value; seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ehwRU/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated & simplified your fiddle a bit : http://jsfiddle.net/ehwRU/3/

```
$("#inputBox, #inputBox2, #commentArea").each(function () {    

    var default_value = $(this).attr("rel");

    $(this).val(default_value)

        .blur(function () { 
            if (!$(this).val().length) $(this).val(default_value); 
         })

        .focus(function () { 
            if ($(this).val() === default_value) $(this).val(""); 
         });
});
```

Seems to work as expected now??

Comment: Thank you so much. I did try to use the placeholder value. But when the search boxes gain focus the text remained until someone began typing. I wished to have the default values removed upon focus for more of a visual emphasis. Everyone's help is so greatly appreciated. I am not sure why my one ellipses is formatted correctly and the other is not. When I copied the condensed one into the textarea it also did work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine to me; you may have mistyped the ellipses or had unnecessary whitespace.  You may want to trim `default_value` for the comparison.

Instead of `rel` you may want to use `placeholder`, which would work without JS in modern browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/ehwRU/1/

Comment: As soon as I read the title I thought of the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: Wow, I feel horrible now but when I type the ellipses I get '...' not what you have which seems to condense them to three closer dots. As well as what I had in the rel field.

I wanted to give a little more visual emphasis that the box has focus than the placeholder does. Unless I am missing something it disappears when you type not on focus.